# Can a 19-year-old drive a New York rental car in Ontario?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, car-rentals, rental

I need a cheap way to move out from college in Toronto and go home to Connecticut, and the minimum age to rent a car there is 20. However, the minimum age in New York is 18, and most companies permit border crossings. Will Canadian or US border agencies give me any trouble for driving a rental across borders at 19? I am a US citizen for context.

Comment: If you're moving, consider a rental truck. You often only have to be 18 to rent one.

Comment: I'm way over 19, but I've driven rental cars from the US into Canada on several occasions, all without incident. Make sure the rental contract explicitly states the rent car can be taken into Canada, and that the rental agency gives you the wallet card showing that the rent car has Canada insurance coverage.

Answer (score 5):

The border agencies have never asked about my drivers license or vehicle registration. They are not tasked with enforcing these laws.

Your issue will be with the rental company. Make sure you will be insured in Canada and that you are permitted to cross the border.

Your US drivers license is valid in Canada.

Comment: They may be interested in the registration if they suspect the car is stolen.